# How to fill a buffer generically and efficiently? (Pass insert iterators? Containers? etc.)

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, buffer

If I'm making a method that needs to fill a buffer (for example, a wrapper for `fread`), and under *some* circumstances (determined at runtime) it can make a good guess at the required buffer size, what should I pass to this method in order to take advantage of this opportunity, while still allowing any reasonable kind of buffer and without requiring multiple calls from the user?

- I'd *like* to use an `insert_iterator`, but then I can't tell it to reserve a certain amount of memory.
- On the other hand, if I pass a *container* as a templated parameter, I'd run into trouble because containers don't have a standard interface! (e.g. `vector` and `string` have `reserve`, but `deque` and `list` don't. Or a container might not have `push_back` -- I don't believe I've seen that being mandatory. etc.)

So what is the appropriate thing to do in a situation like this?

Comment: If you intend to support `stack`, `insert_iterator` will not work.  And `string` also has `push_back`, which `insert_iterator` does not call, but `back_inserter` does.  `insert_iterator` calls `insert`, which, like `push_back`, is supported by both `vector` and `string`, but not `stack`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Oh hmm, interesting point. So you think I should just take the container by reference and call `reserve` and `push_back`, without using iterators at all? (I could probably ignore `stack`... hmm)

Comment: My opinion on what you should do is not solid at this point.  I'm still contemplating it.  I was simply pointing out that your desire for a standard interface (if you want to include stack) is not satisfied by either of the two options in your bullet points.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Ah I see. Let me edit the question a bit actually... I think `stack` is too restrictive.

Comment: Why not have the caller optionally provide a lambda to call that's given the object and size?

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Hmm, that *would* work, but then it would mean that for every container argument, I'd need a corresponding functor argument... which gets a bit ugly/verbose, especially without support for lambdas. It's a possibility though.

Comment: If you expect a very large number of call sites, then you can use the kind of has_member predicates that you'll find in boost or all over stack overflow... just work through the three or four varieties from standard containers and anything custom you have.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Hmm, I'll consider that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create very generic function that takes iterators, then create a family of more specialized functions that take the various sequence container types (vector, list, deque, string), and take appropriate action before forwarding to the more general function, for example:

```
template<typename OutputIterator>
fill_buffer_iterator_version(OutputIterator it)
{
    // fill data through output iterator
} 

// default generic version uses back_inserter, all standard
// sequence containers support push_back
template<typename Container>
fill_buffer(Container & c)
{
    fill_buffer_iterator_version(std::back_inserter(c));
}

// specialize for vector   
fill_buffer(std::vector<char> & v)
{
    v.reserve(100);
    fill_buffer_iterator_version(std::back_inserter(v));
}
```

Comment: Ugh, this would create *so* many copies of my function... but at least it would work, +1 I guess

Answer (score 0):

You know how many bytes you are going to read, so use `resize` method before calling `fread`. Pass, `begin` to it. Or, in customized (templated) version, you may pass the container (by reference), allocate memory for it before "file-read" and do the same thing.

Comment: What if the user gives me something that doesn't support `resize`, like (say) `list`?